# Power Off - Emergency Button

Tags: android-go, emergency-calls

I have a new Android 13 Go phone.

When I press and hold the power button, the power-off screen shows. It has the options; 'Emergency', 'Power Off' and 'Restart'.

How do I change the settings so that 'Emergency' option does NOT appear?

(In fact how do I turn off all things like that; Emergency buttons, Earthquake Warnings, Alien Invasions etc?)

Comment: I don't believe you can disable the "Emergency" button in the power-off menu, but the alerts can be found under "Wireless Emergency Alerts" in settings. It's location and options can vary by phone, but on my Pixel it's under "Safety & emergency," and can be found quickly by searching in Settings.